# Getting null when accessing to HTMLcollection

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tabs, htmlcollection

I have 4 tabs with a list in order to give them the title. I want to access the titles of each tab, but I can only access the whole HTMLcollection. Using react.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Component} from 'react';

class tabs extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"tabs"}>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Class 1</a></li>
                    <li><a>Class 2</a></li>
                    <li><a>Class 3</a></li>
                    <li><a>Class 4</a></li>
                </ul>

                {console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("li"))};
                //full collection with length of 4

                 {console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("li").length)};
                 //0


       {console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("li").item(0).innerHTML)};
                  //"Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null"

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default tabs;
```

Comment: this works for me

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The correct solution will probably not include accessing the DOM at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you declare JSX it doesn't immediately get printed into DOM. First, it will be transpiled by Babel and after the `render` hook React will update the DOM. But hey, in a middle of that you tried to already access these DOM elements...

Comment: So, when should I try to access the DOM ? componentDidMount ?

Comment: @NelsonSilva exactly! https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount  - "Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here"

Comment: That did it, thank you ! Still getting used to reacts lifecycle hooks

Comment: @NelsonSilva The real question is: why do you think that you need to access the DOM at all. Usually you should avoid accessing the DOM directly or at least use `refs`. This seems to be [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/364724).

Comment: I agree you shouldn't rely on accessing DOM directly unless you are working with third-party libraries.

Comment: Im new to react, so it is quite likely that Im not using the best line of thought. I want to catch the title of each tab so I can show 
the corresponding div and hide the others. Using bulma

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do? If you just want the number of `li`s at some point, use a `ref`

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.el.children.length) // 4
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul ref={ el => this.el = el }>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to pass the text in it to a method so I can do something according the tab Im in.

Comment: @TylerSebastian kind regards from Berlin :) Having dinner now.

Comment: @TylerSebastian That was actually not what I said. I said that it should just be `this.el.children.length`. [String refs are deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs) and will likely be removed in future releases of react. I would never recommend using them.